# Error in Chrome when i use AJAX

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Ok i have been working in Ajax and when i run it in IE it works fine
this is the HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq4qhxqtqpgjd57/ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when i run it in Chrome, it gets me this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq4qhxqtqpgjd57/ajax_info.txt. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I try using –allow-file-access-from-files but it did not work or maybe i used wrong

also someone can explain me why this error occur?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: i dont really understand that answer

Answer (score 0):

you should check for the access rights in dropbox settings for that DIR of files.

Comment: i check is in the public folder
and is running smoothly in IE

Comment: i run this in browser : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq4qhxqtqpgjd57/ajax_info.txt 
showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already included JQuery to your page. Just use

```
$('#myDiv').load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq4qhxqtqpgjd57/ajax_info.txt");
```

Using JQuery will let you ignore browser compatibility issues and will make your code more readable.

Comment: as a replacement of you whole function body. From `function loadXMLDoc() {` to `}`.